# Forming a polynomial from the input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to write a program that, when provided inputs by the user, will create a polynomial based on the position of the input order.
For example, if the user input: `1 2 3`
The polynomial should be printed `x^2 + (2.0)x^1 + 3` and this answer should be in float form. How do I do that?

This is what I have done so far

```
def get_expression(x1):

   x1=""
   power = len(x1) - 1

   for i in range(len(x1)):
      if x1[i] < 0:
         x1 += str(x1[i])
      else:
         x1 += "+" + str(x1[i])
    
      if x1[i] == 0:
         continue

      if power == 1:
         x1 += "x"
      elif power == 0:
         x1 = x1
      else:
         x1 += "x" + str(power)

      power = power - 1 

   if sum(x1)==0:
     return float(0)

   return x1
```

The code should satisfy the code below and give results correctly in the form: `-4.5x - 5` & `2x^2 - 3`

```
p1=[-4.5,-5.0]
print(get_expression(p1))
p2=[2.0,0.0,-3.0]
print(get_expression(p2))
```

Please help me and advise how I could correct my code and get an answer in float form.

Comment: First of all, please format your code. Indentation is code in Python. Then, you immediately overwrite `x1` with an empty string. How did you imagine you could retrieve the polynomial coefficients?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) introduction tour.

Comment: I think you used x1 as both the parameter and the result. You have to sort that out.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the string naively and then make it look nicer with string replacements:

```
def poly(*C):
    result = "+".join(f" {c}x^{-p} " for p,c in enumerate(C,1-len(C)) if c)
    result = result.replace("+ -","- ")   # subtract for negative coefficient
    result = result.replace("^1 "," ")    # implicit x^1
    result = result.replace("x^0","")     # implicit x^0
    result = result.replace(" 1x"," x").replace("-1x","-x") # implicit 1x
    return result.strip()
```

for example: poly(-1,0,3,-1,5)

```
result = ' -1x^4 + 3x^2 + -1x^1 + 5x^0 ' # naive build (skips zero coeff.)
result = ' -1x^4 + 3x^2 - 1x^1 + 5x^0 '  # subtract for negative coefficient
result = ' -1x^4 + 3x^2 - 1x + 5x^0 '    # implicit x^1
result = ' -1x^4 + 3x^2 - 1x + 5 '       # implicit x^0
result = ' -x^4 + 3x^2 - x + 5 '         # implicit 1x
return   '-x^4 + 3x^2 - x + 5'           # strip extra space for return
```

output:

```
print(poly(1,2,3))             # x^2 + 2x + 3

print(poly(-4.5,-5))           # -4.5x - 5
print(poly(2,0,-3))            # 2x^2 - 3

print(poly(-1,0,-1.5,5,0,-32)) # -x^5 - 1.5x^3 + 5x^2 - 32
print(poly("a","b","-c"))      # ax^2 + bx - c
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of follow your logic and re-write your code, FYI.

```
def get_expresultsion(x1):
    result = ""  # use another variable instead of x1
    power = len(x1) - 1

    for i in range(len(x1)):
        if x1[i] < 0:
            result += str(x1[i])
        elif x1[i] == 0:
            # put this into the same IF logic since this part is checking x1[i] as well
            power = power - 1
            continue
        else:
            result += "+" + str(x1[i])

        # check power then
        if power == 1:
            result += "x"
        elif power == 0:
            pass
        else:
            # add "^"
            result += "x^" + str(power)
        power = power - 1
    if sum(x1) == 0:
        return float(0)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of viewing your question, I couldn't understand the logic you were following so I wrote it from scratch as simple as I can.

```
def get_expression(coefficient_list):
    power = 0
    expression = "" #Our final result (instead of x1)
    
    if len(coefficient_list) == 1: #For the case having just the constant
        return(coefficient_list[0])

    elif len(coefficient_list) > 1:
        for coefficient in reversed(coefficient_list): #We reverse the list 
        
            if power == 0: #Dealing with constant
                expression += str(coefficient)
                
            else: #Here it puts the coeff and power together and adds to the left side of expression
                expression = f"({coefficient})x^{power} + " + expression
                
            power += 1
            
    return expression
```